# Css selector get text outside tag

Tags: css, css-selectors, lxml, lxml.html

I have the following **HTML**:

```
<label id="w-57265">
<div class="radio same-option-inline" id="inline-condition-108103" style="border-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;">
    <span class="">
        <input type="radio" name="option[57265]" value="108103">
        26EU <span class="specialPricevar" data-price="44.10 AED"></span>
        <span class="realPricevar" data-price="77.70 AED"></span>
        <small style="display: none;">Foot Size 16.5cm</small>
    </span>
    <span id="tickmark" class=""></span>
</div>
```

I want to get **"26EU"** via css selector using *lxml*

i had already tried this

```
doc.cssselect('label .same-option-inline')
```

but it returned all of text in the tag

> 26EU
>
> Foot Size 16.2cm

what is the correct method to get **"26EU"** and **"Foot Size 16.2cm"** each one alone ? (without spaces)

Comment: That text does not appear in your code.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo now it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can try being more specific for Foot Size
`doc.cssselect('label .same-option-inline small')` will return "Foot Size 16.5cm"

However, you cannot directly get 26EU as it's not encapsulated in any tag on it's own (It is wrapped in `<span class="">` but so is Foot Size. That is why you are getting both these entities together.)

You can try replacing 25EU with `<p>25EU</p>` and then using `doc.cssselect('label .same-option-inline p')`

This will return only 25EU.